# Client-appended fields not working with Django forms validation

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

As a passive captcha solution, I want to add a field to a Django form with jQuery, set its value, then validate it on the server.

So far, the first part is working, the second part is maybe working, and the third part is not working...

in the JS:

```
var it_is_init = function(){

    var check = 'Verhoven'
    $(document.createElement('input'))
        .attr({type: 'hidden',
               name: 'ROBOCOP',
               id: 'robocop',
               placeholder:'Leave this blank'
        })
        .val('')

        .appendTo($('form'));

    $('input').focus(
        function(e){
            $('#robocop').val(check);}
        )
};  
$(document).ready(static_init);
```

and this *seems* to be working on the client side, in that after the page loads, in the Chrome console `$('#robocop')` evaluates to  `[<input type="hidden" name="ROBOCOP" id="robocop" placeholder="Leave this blank" value>]`, then tabbing or clicking into one of the relevant fields and evaluating `$('#robocop')` yields `[<input type="hidden" name="ROBOCOP" id="robocop" placeholder="Leave this blank" value="Verhoven">]`. All this is as expected and intended.

On the server, though, the value `Verhoven` never shows up, though the field `ROBOCOP` does.

*edit* I now suspect I'm not setting the field properly with jQuery, in that examining the `request.raw_post_data` shows the `ROBOCOP` field is blank. What is the right way to set that value so it shows up in the POST data?

in the `clean_FIELDNAME` method of another field (captcha), I'm running `pprint(self.data)` where `self` is the instance of the `ModelForm` that is being returned. this is the result:

```
<QueryDict: {
 u'first_name': [u'Arnold'],
 u'last_name': [u'Palmer'], 
 u'ROBOCOP': [u''], 
 u'captcha': [u'b7e94363137363837303431320934'],
 u'visit_date': [u''],
 u'message': [u''],
 u'email': [u'john@example.com'],
 u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'b358e41c435a05aa53e582ed21dd3b79']}>
```

So, why is `ROBOCOP` the empty string in `self.fields`

Comment: How did `name="ROBOCOP" id="robocop"` turn into `name="HP" id="hp"`?

Comment: that was my mistake, in editing this for public consumption, I mismunged some names. corrected in the edit